# Error running Python program: 'module not found

Tags: python, pandas, modulenotfounderror

I'm working on a Python program and I'm running into an error that says 'module not found'. Here's the code that's causing the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Comment: Have you installed the pandas package with pip or conda?

Comment: you have to install the library e.g. `pip install pandas`

Comment: may be: before that you activated venv and now it deactivated.
btw: Should check use venv in python.

Answer (score 0):

just simply open command prompt and type the following command:

```
    pip install pandas
    pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```